# ImportError: cannot import name 'Weather'

Tags: python, importerror

I just copied and pasted this code from the documentation page and I used pip to successfully install the package yet I keep running into this error:

```
  File "c:\Users\Guppy\Desktop\RACHEAL\RACHEALs Tools\Applications\Weather\weather.py", line 1, in <module>
    from weather import Weather
ImportError: cannot import name 'Weather'
```

Heres the code:

```
from weather import Weather

weather = Weather()

# Lookup WOEID via http://weather.yahoo.com.

lookup = weather.lookup(560743)
condition = lookup.condition()
print(condition.text())

# Lookup via location name.

location = weather.lookup_by_location('dublin')
condition = location.condition()
print(condition.text())

# Get weather forecasts for the upcoming days.

forecasts = location.forecast()
for forecast in forecasts:
    print(forecast.text())
    print(forecast.date())
    print(forecast.high())
    print(forecast.low())
```

Does anyone know what's wrong or any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you using any virtual environment or conda environment? Or by any chance you are using any different versions of python for installation and running your code?

Answer (score 1):

Use python 2.x for this, I believe weather API is not working for Python 3 just by installing it through pip.

You might have to re-install it for it to work on Python3.x using `pip3`

You can try: `pip3 install weather-api`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a name conflict between your test program, `weather.py`, and the  module you're trying to use; Python is trying to load the `Weather` class from your program instead of the module.  Try renaming your tester and also delete associated `weather.pyc` and/or a `__pycache__` directory if they exist.

Answer (score 0):

Pip occasionally installs packages to your local interpreter, or to a virtual_env, when your runtime is looking at the other of the two.

Figure out where pip is installing the module, and then check sys.path to see if that directory is listed. If not, that's your issue. Add is to path or install somewhere it will be found.